# Why my font color will chang when div transition?

Tags: html, css

Here is also on jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/phmttrsh/

```css
#btn {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #20ACB3;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 34px;
    background-color: #20ACB3;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.39, 0.39, 2.01);
}

 #btn:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
```

```html
<div id="btn">Click</div>
```

When on hover on button the font color will also change very short time and it only happened on safari.

Why this happened?

Comment: It might be cause of  User agent style sheets. User agent style sheets are overridden by anything that you set in your own style sheet. Consult section [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) .
And be ensure `<!DOCTYPE>` is included.
Add your own color style against element .

Answer (score 2):

```css
#btn {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #20ACB3;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 34px;
    background-color: #20ACB3;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition : transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.39, 0.39, 2.01) , color 200ms; 
   -moz-transition : transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.39, 0.39, 2.01) , color 200ms;
    -o-transition : transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.39, 0.39, 2.01) , color 200ms; 
    transition : transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.39, 0.39, 2.01) , color 200ms; 
}

 #btn:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        transform: scale(1.05);
        color:#fff
    }
```

```html
<div id="btn">Click</div>
```

Comment: care to explain it a bit?

Comment: Add this, my transform transition will not fire.